# Motivation/intuition behind the definition of delta-functors and related concepts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-functors

1. Why are $\delta$-functors between abelian categories $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ defined as a collection of (right) derived functors, and connecting morphisms $\delta^i: T^i(A'') \rightarrow T^{i+1}(A')$ (given an original short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A' \rightarrow A \rightarrow A'' \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathfrak{A}$)
   $$(T^*, \delta^*) := \{(T^i, \delta^i)\}_{i \geq 0}$$
   Particularly, in the context of algebraic geometry, what about this definition is geometric ?
2. What is a geometric interpretation of the universality of $\delta$-functors ?
3. What is a geometric interpretation of effaceable $\delta$-functors, and by extension, theorem 2.2.2 in Grothendieck's Tohoku paper stating that effaceability implies universality ?
   [image: The theorem as found in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry]

Comment: For 1), the motivation behind it is the connecting homomorphism for usual cohomology. One always want to cook up a long exact sequence in $\delta$-functors from a short exact sequence of objects (think about complexes of abelian groups and cohomology in each degree).

Comment: $\delta$-functors have geometric *motivations* and *applications*, but it seems a bit too much to ask for a geometric *interpretation* of something which is inherently a pure piece of homological algebra, re 2 and 3. Similarly for 1: nothing about the definition is particularly geometric.